# Missing logcat? KMSG? Debugging random reboots

Tags: reboot, logging, android-12, debug

I have this crap [ANS ARTIA](https://www.assurancewireless.com/application/files/2316/6601/6859/ANS-Artia_User_GuideV1.1-0704-EN_002.pdf) phone running Android 12. It keeps rebooting—2-3 times at the same date/time of the week (once while using G Maps, once using Waze) plus a couple more times outside of those circumstances. I'm broke and can't afford anything else, so I'm trying to fix it.

One time it crashed to that dead android screen and the power button wouldn't even work. I had to do PWR+VOL UP like I was trying to get into fastboot just to reboot it.

I saved 2 bug reports so far, one being quickly after a reboot. Online docs say to look for logcat.txt, but there isn't one in these reports, only dumpstate_log, main_entry, and version.txt in the parent folder, with several other folders. Someone said look for LAST KMSG, but the only mention of that is:

> *** Error dumping /proc/last_kmsg (LAST KMSG): No such file or
> directory  ------ 0.001s was the duration of 'LAST KMSG' ------

I'll watch for it to happen again and try to capture another report immediately after, but I don't know how to recreate it on demand while plugged in to USB. I have ADB and Android Studio, but I don't know what to do with them.
No results for am_anr. There are 4 files in \data\anr. No WATCHDOG KILLING, no am_focused_activity,

> VM TRACES AT LAST ANR (/data/anr/anr_2023-06-08-16-07-26-347:
> 2023-06-08 16:07:32) ------
> Subject: Input dispatching timed out (e036911 NavigationBar0 (server) is not responding. Waited 9633ms for MotionEvent)

Someone said type *#9900# to turn on more verbose logging, but I get "invalid mmi code," and my carrier is a crappy free provider so that may never work.

I got a bunch of am_proc_died at 17:39 and a bunch of am_proc_start around the same timestamp. I got 4 am_low_memory's but that was at a different timestamp.
A few hits for kswapd, a ton of hits for kworker, but I don't know what I'm looking for. No hits for mmcqd. No Uncaught remote exceptions.

> Line  11865: 12-31 18:00:15.858  1000  1644  1644 W PackageManager:
> There should probably be exactly one storage manager; found 2:
> matches=[ResolveInfo{5cce669
> com.google.android.apps.nbu.files/.home.HomeActivity p=100
> m=0x108000}, ResolveInfo{4a848ee
> com.android.storagemanager/.deletionhelper.DeletionHelperActivity
> m=0x108000}]
> Line 569647: 06-08 17:41:52.782 10221 15908 15908 E
> HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: resolveInfoList is null or empty    Line
> 569653: 06-08 17:41:52.789 10221 15908 15908 E
> HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: resolveInfoList is null or empty    Line
> 569657: 06-08 17:41:52.796 10221 15908 15908 E
> HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: resolveInfoList is null or empty

> Line  27951: 06-08 17:42:58.876  1000 19810 19810 I
> ResolverListAdapter: Add DisplayResolveInfo component:
> ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.docs/com.google.android.apps.docs.common.shareitem.UploadMenuActivity},
> intent component:
> ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.docs/com.google.android.apps.docs.common.shareitem.UploadMenuActivity}
>
> Line  27952: 06-08 17:42:58.877  1000 19810 19810 I
> ResolverListAdapter: Add DisplayResolveInfo component:
> ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmailExternal},
> intent component:
> ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmailExternal}
>
> Line  28288: 06-08 17:43:06.745  1000 19810 19810 D ChooserActivity:
> ResolveInfo Package is com.google.android.apps.docs
> Line  34987:
> 06-08 17:42:20.993  1000  1644  2177 I am_broadcast_discard_app:
> [0,180397340,android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED,3,ResolveInfo{15d3531
> com.qti.ltebc/com.qualcomm.ltebc.LTEBroadcastReceiver m=0x208000}]
>
> Line  35064: 06-08 17:42:28.965  1000  1644  1902 I
> am_broadcast_discard_app:
> [0,65709818,android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED,3,ResolveInfo{7d87402
> com.qti.ltebc/com.qualcomm.ltebc.LTEBroadcastReceiver m=0x208000}]
>
> Line  35225: 06-08 17:42:49.671  1000  1644  2174 I
> am_broadcast_discard_app:
> [0,229308146,com.microsoft.bing.usbsdk.api.APPWIDGET_UPDATE,0,ResolveInfo{d90e5a1
> com.microsoft.bing/com.microsoft.clients.bing.widget.SearchBoxWidgetProvider
> m=0x0}]

Can someone please tell me why I don't have logcat or dumpsys? And can anyone tell me what to look for in these logs that might give me an idea of what is happening? Thanks!!!

Comment: Where have you read about `logcat.txt` ? Logcat is an in-memory ring buffer that is to my knowledge never saved to flash. Logcat.txt only exists if you connect the phone to your PC and capture logcat to a file on your PC. If the phone then crashes while connected to the PC you have a logcat.txt file.

Comment: https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/debug/read-bug-reports               "Android bug reports contain dumpsys, dumpstate, and logcat data in text (.txt) format"

Comment: That is the documentatio for app developers. An Android bug report is generated when an app crashes, not when the OS crashes.